# Start an android service inside the same service to make a loop

Tags: android, image-processing, android-intent

I'm making an app for real time image processing. For that, I made a service to capture an image without using an user interface. Now, I want to start this service again and again so that each time the service starts, it takes an image, process it, and then starts again and so on.... 
I'm doing this by starting a timer at the end of the process in the service and then restart the service in the `onFinish()` method of that timer, like this:

```
new CountDownTimer(3000,1000){

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { }

    public void onFinish() {
        mCamera.release();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.helpingproject.CameraService");
        startService(intent);
        Log.d("Tag1222", "timer finished");
    }
}.start();
```

Can anybody please help me in this? "timer finished" appears in the log but the service does not start again.

Comment: Starting and restarting a service is not a good use of a service. Better to move the functionality to *within* your service.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a thread in your service and put while loop there like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(true)
    {
       Thread.sleep(60000) 
       //REST OF CODE HERE//
    }

                    }
}).start();
```

**But this is an easy quick fix, overall, creating a thread that sleeps all the time is not a good solution for mobile devices.**

You should consider using [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead. It handles recurring events very well and was specifically designed for similar scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Use a service running in background and then, everytime you want to work with the picture start a thread.